# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start throwing threadabort exception on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.diagnostics, threadabortexception

In my website I am using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to preview a particular file. It is working fine on the local server but, it throws ThreadAbortException on the online server when I try to preview the file.

The preview of the happens on button click of repeater. The code is given below:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Preview")
            {
                Button btn = (Button)e.CommandSource;
                string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload");
                string _DownloadableProductFileName = filename;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath + "\\" + _DownloadableProductFileName);
            }
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Also check the IIS settings, it might be some permission issue.

Comment: @Naren please re check the edit code

Answer (score 1):

To use Process on the ASP.NET server you need to [configure the application for Full Trust.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx)

Are you sure you need to spawn this process server side? It seems you aren't using its output.

Comment: I just want the user to preview the file contents without downloading it.

Comment: What types of files are these?

Comment: microsoft office files: word, presentations, etc.